# Page does not finish loading after the code has ran Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Once I finish running my code, the page takes about 15 minutes to finish loading.

Is there anyway to ensure that the page loads completely?

When this process is done manually in a normal Chrome page, it updates in a matter of seconds. Even doing things manually in the Automated Chrome page also takes a very very long time.

**Actual**
[image]

And I am getting the following messages:

VM102 jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

VM102 jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

VM102 jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

[image]

**Expected**
[image]

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="cnfield1">

    <input name="numbers" type="text" class="inputmember" value="" 
    style="width:130px;ime-mode:disabled;text-transform:uppercase;" onkeydown="if 
    (window.event.keyCode == 13) { validateSearchFormCTP(); }"> 

    <input name="numbers" type="text" class="inputmember" value="" 
    style="width:130px;ime-mode:disabled;text-transform:uppercase;" onkeydown="if 
    (window.event.keyCode == 13) { validateSearchFormCTP(); }"> 

    <input name="numbers" type="text" class="inputmember" value="" 
    style="width:130px;ime-mode:disabled;text-transform:uppercase;" onkeydown="if 
    (window.event.keyCode == 13) { validateSearchFormCTP(); }"> 

    <a class="new_btn02" href="javascript:makeField('cn');">+ADD</a>
</div>

<td class="text_R">
    <a class="new_btn03" id="resetBtn" href="#">Reset</a>
    <a class="new_btn08" id="inquiryBtn" href="#">Inquiry</a>
</td>
```

**Python Code:**

```
options = WD.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

driver = WD.Chrome(r" driver.exe path")

    Lst=['HDMU2795525']
    driver.get('https://www.hmm21.com/cms/business/ebiz/trackTrace/trackTrace/index')

    time.sleep(2)
    
    driver.switch_to.frame('_frame1')
        
    for j in Lst:
        
        #Insert container number
        time.sleep(2)
        
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'and @class='inputmember'][1]").send_keys(j)
        
        time.sleep(2)

        #Search
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='inquiryBtn']").click()
```

Comment: Try also to add `options.add_argument("user-agent=<USER AGENT>")` option (replace `<USER AGENT>` with real value)

Comment: @DonnyFlaw thanks for the feedback! I used the agent but the speed is still the same:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"

Comment: Can you open the network console to see if any of the ajax requests are being blocked?

Comment: @DMart, do you have an example on how to do that? I am not an expert so I am learning on my own. Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: @DMart Hey so I looked into the network console and found 2 errors and 1 warning that I edited up above.

Comment: Neither of those seem relevant. I'm not sure why it's taking the page any longer to load. I'm guessing it might be detected as an automated browser, but that's just a theory.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to ensure that the page loads completely?

Generally you should set [wait condition](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) for each operated DOM element (get rid of all `time.sleep(2)` in your code)

For example (multiple elements):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
# ...
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//div")))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to ensure that the page loads completely?

I would use a webdriver wait, until the "loading" element disappears:

```
waitTime = (60 * 1000) * 15 #15 minutes
WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime).until(EC.staleness_of((By.XPATH, "//*/xpath/loading")))
```

You'll have to update the xpath of course.

Comment: I actually tried this, and the page didnt load at all. So I kept it with time sleep for now.

Comment: When you say didn't load at all, do you mean the web site? Or your code timed out?